# Setup Raspberry Pi3 as NTP server (not using external NTP server)

Tags: server, raspberry-pi3, ntp

I've searched around, but I cannot find an answer.

Can I use my Raspberry Pi as an NTP server (independently).

I want to synchronize 4 devices on a LAN for logging. They will be on a LAN with no WAN access... one is a Cisco Switch, one is the Pi and the other two are conversion boxes I want to log things on (they will be NTP client).

I just need them all to sysnc to 1 clock source (the Pi) is there a way to do this? All the answers I find are either to setup the Pi with a GPS module (which I can't do here) or sync it to external NTP servers for cascading the clock down (which I can't do here)... can I use NTP just to send out the Pi's system time ?

Answer (score 0):

You could but best with a time source.
You would need to edit the code for a NTP server, as there isn't much cause to do this.

Best idea is to use a GPS hat on the RPi
http://www.reeve.com/Documents/Articles%20Papers/Reeve_GpsNtp-Pi.pdf

Answer (score 0):

DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far...

On your Raspberry Pi, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ntp
sudo ufw allow ntp  # if your firewall is enabled
sudo ufw allow 123
sudo sed --in-place --expression "\$aserver 127.127.1.0" /etc/ntp.conf
sudo systemctl start ntpd
```

On your Cisco switch, run the following commands:

**NOTE** - If you are using Cisco IOS, do not forget to force the NTP synchronization using `clock read-calendar`.

```
configure terminal
ntp server <the IPv4 address of your Raspberry Pi>
end
clock read-calendar
```

**PS** - If you want to shut everything down...

On your Raspberry Pi, run the following commands:

```
sudo ufw delete allow ntp
sudo ufw delete allow 123
sudo systemctl stop ntpd
sudo sed -i "/server 127.127.1.0/d" /etc/ntp.conf
```

On your Cisco switch, run the following commands:

```
configure terminal
no ntp server <the IPv4 address of your Raspberry Pi>
end
```